# Visual C++ - Function call with a function as parameter: change leads to unresolved external

Tags: c++, visual-c++

The last line I keep getting the error, unresolved external.

```
bool checker(string roman);
// Adds each value of the roman numeral together
int toDecimal(string, bool (function)(string));
int convert(string roman, int i);

int main(){
    string roman;
    cout << "This program takes a roman numeral the user enters then converts it to decimal notation." << endl;
    cout << "Enter a roman numeral: ";
    cin >> roman;
    transform(roman.begin(), roman.end(), roman.begin(), toupper);
    cout << roman << " is equal to " << toDecimal(roman,  *checker) << endl;
}
```

If I change the prototypes to

```
int convert(string roman, int i);
int toDecimal(string, bool* (*function)(string));
```

and last line to

```
cout << roman << " is equal to " << toDecimal(roman, *checker(roman)) << endl;
```

I get

> illegal indirection, "Error   2   error C2664: 'toDecimal' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'bool' to 'bool *(__cdecl *)(std::string)'"

and

> Operand of (*) must be a pointer

Comment: Have you heard about functor?

Comment: no, not a clue what that is

Answer (score 1):

This is how you should use a pointer to funciton:

```
bool (*pToFunc) (string) = checker;
```

This is mean that `pToFunc` is a pointer to function that return *bool* and get *string* as a parameter, and points to `checker`.

Now send this pointer to function to your function this way:

```
cout << roman << " is equal to " << toDecimal(roman,  pToFunc) << endl;
```

**Don't forget you have to implement checker**

But, you are writing in C++, and there is a much better way to achieve what you are looking for. It could functor.

This is how you should do it, using functor:

*define functor:*

```
class romanFunctor {
   public:
     bool operator()(string roman) {\\ checker implementetion}
};
```

*example how to use:*

```
romanFunctor checker ;
string roman;
cin >> roman;
if (checker(roman) == true) {...}
```

Comment: Can't see how the functor object is better here.

Comment: You can't pass that to `toDecimal` with either (1) hardcoding the function to call or (2) using templates, which I think are too advanced for this user.

Comment: I was raised to always prefer OOP and generic.

Comment: @BenVoigt "You can't pass that to.." by **that** you mean to?

Comment: By "that" I mean your functor object.

Comment: I can't see what is the problem with `int toDecimal(string, romanFunctor); romanFunctor checker; toDecimal(roman, checker);`

Comment: That hardcodes the function to call.  You've made `romanFunctor`, which contains the behavior, part of `toDecimal`'s signature.  It's not generic, and there's no longer any point in even making it a parameter.  On the other hand, a function pointer allows connecting any behavior with the right argument types and return type.

Comment: not genric? It is the most generic you can get! If you want to change the logic of the check function all you have to do is inherit from romanFunctor and override the () operator.

Comment: No, that won't work at all.  If you declare `int toDecimal(string, romanFunctor);`, there is no way to pass a derived object to that function.  Haven't you heard of *slicing*?  It is hard-coded to call exactly `romanFunctor::operator()()`.  You could use a template, or `std::function` with type-erasure.  But those topics are way more advanced than your answer.

Comment: ohh I see what disturbing you..It upposed to be `int toDecimal(string, romanFunctor*);`

Comment: You need one more change to make it work with a derived class.  But you almost never see functors passed by pointer or reference.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem here:

```
int toDecimal(string, bool (function)(string));
```

You're declaring `function` as a parameter of function type.  But functions can't be passed by value (how do you make a copy of a function?).  Instead, you need to accept a pointer to a function.

```
int toDecimal(string, bool (*fnptr)(string));
```

Just one `*`, next to the argument name.  The return type is still `bool` and not `bool*`.

Then, you need to pass a pointer to the function.  This is wrong:

```
toDecimal(roman,  *checker)
```

To make a pointer, you use `&` to get the address and `*` later to dereference.  Functions aren't much different in this regard, except that conversions between functions and function pointers are implicit *in some circumstances*.  I prefer to be explicit.  So that call should be:

```
toDecimal(roman, &checker)
```